# How to set minutes to a schedule reporting task in pega

Tags: pega

I want to set time for the

> Time of Day

in schedule reporting task to 10.30.But we can set only hours in the pega UI.

[image]

can anyone help me with setting time with minutes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not out of the box. You would need to change a property named `pyMinimumDateTimeForProcessing`, and that can be done using a Data Transform (or an Activity). Here's an excellent summary how scheduled reports work: https://myknowpega.com/2019/12/12/schedule-reports-pega/. You can see where aforementioned property resides at the following heading:

> 2. Pega creates a new queue instance for the agent

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`pyScheduleTaskInfo` is the `Flow Action` which is called on schedule report. Which is not a `Final` rule. That means you can modify this flow action.

If you look into 16th step of post processing Activity `pzPostProcess`(a 'Final' activity), you will find below lines.

```
int hour = myStepPage.getInteger(".pyTimeOfDay");
int minute= myStepPage.getInteger(".pyMinuteOfHour");
int second = myStepPage.getInteger(".pySecondOfMinute");
```

But, in the flow action `section` `pyTaskScheduling`, only `pyTimeofDay` is used. This is not a `final` section. Hence, you can save as it your ruleset.

`pyMinuteOfHour` and `pySecondOfMinute` are not used in the section. And these properties are no longer present in class `Embed-ScheduledTask-Scheduling` which is the primary class for section `pyTaskScheduling`. Hence you can not use these properties in section `pyTaskScheduling` .

You need to first save as section `pyTaskScheduling`(with same name and same class) in your ruleset.

Then add new properties just after `hour`  dropdown to select minutes and seconds.

Save as activity `pzPostProcess` in your ruleset with other name and same class(since its final rule, name should be different) and modify below two lines of Java step 16.

```
int minute= myStepPage.getInteger(".pyMinuteOfHour"); // instead of pyMinuteofHour, add your property
int second = myStepPage.getInteger(".pySecondOfMinute"); // instead of pySecondOfMinute, add your property
```

Now save as flowaction `pyScheduleTaskInfo` in your ruleset(with same name and same class) and replace the post processing activity with your activity.

I have not tried this solution but you can try it.